# Not printing to the console upon establishing connection to the server

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm currently following a Udemy course that's having me use flask and socketio to use a neural network model to drive a simulated car. However, as he's explaining the basics of how flask and socketio work, he had us write this code:

```
import socketio
import eventlet
from flask import Flask


sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)


@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connected')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 4567)), app)
```

Which is supposed to print "Connected!" to the console when we connect to the server. Now, I get this message when I run it, so I'm pretty sure I'm connected.

```
(7532) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 49374)
```

But it's refusing to print "Connected!" when I connect like it's supposed to, no matter what I try.

EDIT:
So, I'm still not sure what the root cause of this is, but I found out how to fix it.

1. conda install python-engineio==3.13.2
2. conda install python-socketio==4.6.1

You might need to run anaconda as an administrator. If so, search for "Anaconda Powershell Prompt" then run it as an admin.

Comment: you could add link to course - maybe it is outdated. And you should show how you connect to this server.

Comment: `socketio` uses special protocol to communicate so you need special `client` to work with this - it will not work with normal web browser. See documentation for example: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#what-is-socket-io . Evetually you can use browser to load web page which will use special JavaScript modules to connect with `socketio`

Comment: @furas

[This](https://www.udemy.com/course/applied-deep-learningtm-the-complete-self-driving-car-course/) is the link to the course. I already know it's a bit outdated. This isn't the first thing I've had to update. But it's all been relatively small changes. This just outright doesn't work and I can't find a reason why.

And I'm not trying to connect to the web. I'm trying to connected to a car sim that can be found [here](https://github.com/udacity/self-driving-car-sim).

Comment: you could add this informations and links in question at start - it could explain a lot at start. If simulation works as server then you should run client, not server. Server is for receiving connections, not to connect to other servers.

Answer (score 1):

`socketio` uses special protocol so you need special client to use it.

At least

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()
con = sio.connect('http://0.0.0.0:4567')
sio.wait()
```

I will not work with web browser. With web browser you can see only `accepted`.

Browser have to load web page which uses special JavaScript module to use `socketio`.

You can find more details in `socketio` documentation: [Client](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html)

---

**EDIT:**

And here `server` which you can test with web browser.

When you open http://0.0.0.0:4567 in browser then `index()` sends to browser `HTML` with `JavaScript` code which loads special library and uses `socketio` to send own event. And you should see `Connected`, `my event`. When you close page or browser then you should see `Disconnected`

It is based on example from documentation for [flask-socketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

```
import socketio
import eventlet
from flask import Flask

sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
Hello World!

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'Im connected!'});
    });
</script>
"""

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connected')

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect(sid):  # without `environ`
    print('Disconnected')

@sio.on('my event')
def my_event(sid, environ):
    print('my event')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 4567)), app)
```

Comment: It's giving me nothing. So maybe it's an issue with my internet or computer?

Comment: this is example: you should run my server and my client at the same time on the same computer because  both use IP `0.0.0.0`